# AT89C51RD2 Empty or don't start up erratically

Tags: programming, microprocessor, atmel, 8051

I have a strange problem and I don't know how to find a solution. I have a board with an [AT89C51RD2](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc4235.pdf) inside. I programmed it (thanks to Atmel flip), and it works fine. After some use (week or months), I find the AT89C51RD2, and it won't start. I have a lot of this board and it doesn't appear on all board...I have no clue where to start.

here is the diagram

[image]

It's an old design and we 'plug" the AT89C51 in it.
Normally, the AT89C851 communicates with the PC an drive some steppers thanks to a tmc chain.
I can't make measure (i can do it in a few weeks)
What we do at the startup is:
CKCON0|=1;
AUXR = 0x10;

Important info, we can reprogrammed it in programmation mode and it works.

Decoupling capa (U1):

[image]

More infos:
We sold a lot (25/30) of systems with this couple (uc/board), and 1 from 2017 have this problem, and two since 2022

Comment: Hello and welcome.  You'll get the best from EE.SE if you post all your details.  "My MCU board didn't work" doesn't give much to work with.  Do you have circuit diagrams, photos?  When it worked, what does it do?

Comment: I add more details

Comment: I update the 1st post.

Comment: Are you sure that all 8051 are ok with 32 MHz ?

Comment: Maybe it's a little bit to high. Does it explain why it works most of time on different boards, since years, and sometimes, on some board, the memory is erased?

Comment: In X2 mode, until 20 MHz (internal or external mode) or 30 MHz (internal mode only).

Comment: @F4F56 - Hi, Interesting problem but too much context & detail is still missing IMHO, so I won't engage yet. For example, your last comment revealed something about things working "most of {the} time" for years". As always for "non-day 1" issues, the detailed timeline of when things worked & when problems started is important to analyse, but is missing here. Also, your title says "AT89C51RD2 Empty". How do you know the flash is *empty*, not just suffering from corruption at location X? Reprogramming would fix both of them. Can you read the flash on that MCU before reprogramming "faulty" units?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. I'm agree Antonio51, we are 2 MHz above. It will be nice if it doesn't work everytime, but it's not the case.

Comment: SamGibson, what kind of infos wil be nice for you? I'm agree with you, we are near "contexteless" here, it's why I post here, to find a way to attack the system. For infos, we sold a lot (25/30) of systems with this couple (uc/board), and 1 from 2017 have this problem, and two since 2022.

Comment: Just do get you "in track": This is not a forum, and as such, our comments are not answers. We are asking for clarifications and give hints what to try and to add to your question. Please [edit] your question and enhance it with new information. Do not post comments for such.

Comment: Confirmed. You are using 32 MHz and mode X2 (CKCKON0=1, max frequency 30 MHz, statistically, this "should" run ... until the use of some "bad" die ). You are just a little above the limit of frequency. Try with just a lower XTAL frequency.

Comment: ok, to confirm your theory Antonia, what we can do is: with a "bad" die as we recievefrom one of our customer: #1on 32MHz board, see if start up (normally no), #2 on modified 24MHz board, see if it start up (validation of your theory). Seems good, no?

Comment: If you can "tolerate" another frequency in place of 32 MHz (24 MHz should be fine), it seems good :-)  NB: if you must use "external mode" (use of external program memory), you should use 20 MHz or perhaps 16 MHz.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately i'm on telework and i have no tools to try 24MHz. But the technician at work said the uc is empty now...so it's in pause now. I come back to you if I have news.